# error creating bean entitymanagerfactory in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create a model for Database in Spring Boot Framework.
I took the example from [here](http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Spring-Generic-DAO-and-Generic-Service-Implementation), but i get an error at runntime:

```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
> Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

Comment: I would suggest use this link as a reference for Spring Boot data JPA https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: If you can share code you have written, we would be able to debug.

Comment: I have changet to use CrudRepository instead of DAO. Seems to work now.